# Python Sockets - Multiple clients one server, where to put input message into server to send to one client

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, python-sockets

I have an industrial robot connected over TCP which recieves a string in bytes. I have successfully done some simple comms between them but I now need to add another client, where the server can send out messages to either client. I'm using selectors and as its a little abstract I'm getting confused.

This is the server code - the client is written in SPEL+ so i won't show it, but is very very simple - Print [port number] [message]

```
import socket
import selectors
import types
import time
import queue

sel = selectors.DefaultSelector()

# # Any data received by this queue will be sent
# send_queue = queue.Queue()

def accept_wrapper(sock):
    conn, addr = sock.accept()  # Should be ready to read
    fd = sock.fileno()
    print(f"Accepted connection from {addr}, FD# {fd}")
    conn.setblocking(False)
    data = types.SimpleNamespace(addr=addr, inb=b"", outb=b"")
    events = selectors.EVENT_READ | selectors.EVENT_WRITE
    sel.register(conn, events, data=data)


def service_connection(key, mask, pending_messages):
    sock = key.fileobj
    data = key.data

    print("Key.fd~~~~~~")
    print(key.fd)
    print("Key.fileobj.fileno()~~~~~~")
    print(key.fileobj.fileno())

    if mask & selectors.EVENT_READ:
        recv_data = sock.recv(1024)  # Should be ready to read
        if recv_data:
            data.outb += recv_data
        else:
            print(f"Closing connection to {data.addr}")
            sel.unregister(sock)
            sock.close()
    if mask & selectors.EVENT_WRITE:
        if len(pending_messages) > 0 and pending_messages[0][0] == key.fd:
            print(pending_messages[0][0])
            data.outb = pending_messages[0][1]
            pending_messages.pop(0)
            print(pending_messages)
        if data.outb:
            print(f"Echoing {data.outb!r} to {data.addr}")
            sent = sock.send(data.outb)  # Should be ready to write
            data.outb = data.outb[sent:]

    time.sleep(1)


def main(host, port):
    #host, port = sys.argv[1], int(sys.argv[2])
    lsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    lsock.bind((host, port))
    lsock.listen()
    print(f"Listening on {(host, port)}")
    lsock.setblocking(False)
    sel.register(lsock, selectors.EVENT_READ, data=None)
    pending_messages = []
    
    try:
        while True:
            events = sel.select(timeout=None)
            for key, mask in events:
                if key.data is None:
                    fd, addr = accept_wrapper(key.fileobj)
                else:
                    pending_messages = [(fd, b"helloWorld\r")]                    
                    service_connection(key, mask, pending_messages)

             
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Caught keyboard interrupt, exiting")
    finally:
        sel.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main("",2000)
```

I thought fd was the interger assigned to the connection within the selector, Also (using many print statements) im not sure how the selector knows that there is data to write.
The code might be familiar as its from RealPython, but like most tutorials im finding they all stop at the server being able to accept a message from other code to then send to a client.

At the moment, I cannot get multi socket server to accept a message to then send it to the client. The client and server do communicate but this is just a basic echo.

Comment: Would a messaging library be of more help to you? e.g. something like [zeroMQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZeroMQ). Slightly old now but looking at [NetworkZero](https://github.com/tjguk/networkzero/tree/master/examples/chat) might give good examples of how it can be used.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into those! I have to use a TCP connection with the robot but have already decided to use something else to communicate with other systems.